# How to find pattern?

Tags: c++, math, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

`Array = [1 3 6];`

We can split  into contiguous segments called pieces and store them as another array B:

```
B=[(1),(3),(6)]; B=1*1+3*1+6*1=10; 
B=[(1,3),6]; B=(1+3)*2+6*1=14;
B=[(1,(3,6)]; B=1*1+(3+6)*2=19;  
B=[(1,3,6)];  B=(1+3+6)*3=30;
```

When we sum all the results, we get `10+14+19+30=73`. That's is the final result for `Array = [1,3,6]`. I want find pattern for any array size like that.

It can be `array[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `array[1,5,6,7]`, `array[5,777,88,11,22]` etc. How can I do that?

Comment: please, format your code, at least. Take care of our eyes.

Comment: And our minds too.

Comment: it is suitable for may be math or codereview.stackexchane.com ... but format is must :P

Comment: I can try format change,but i can't figure out.@Andrii

Comment: if array size=[1,2,3,4] it's split is B=[(1) (2) (3) (4)]
B=[(1 2) (3) (4)]
B=[(1) (2 3) (4)]
B=[(1) (2) (3 4)]
B=[(1 2) (3 4)]
B=[(1 2 3) (4)]
B=[(1) (2 3 4)]
B=[(1 2 3 4)]

Answer (score 1):

To code this you probably want a recursive solution. Something like

```
int solve(int[] data) {
    int len = data.length;
    if(len ==1 ) return data[0];

    // for the full sequence (1,2,3,4,5) its just he length times 
    // the sum
    int res = sum(data) * len;

    // now consider partitions
    for(int i=0;i<len-1;++i) {
        res += solve(data[0 .. i] )
        res += solve(data[i+1 .. len-1])
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: If we get array size 10^6.This recursive solution getting TLE ,For that need pattern 0(1) or 0(nlong) solution for that. Thanks for reply @salix

Comment: You might be getting into combinatorial problems with an array that size. Your problem is closely linked to [Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). We can get an estimate the number of partitions. With an array length of 10,000 there are approximately 3.6E106 partitions, far bigger than its going to be possible to calculate. A non-recursive solution might be able to increase the max size a bit but it will still run into a limit.